# How to set Qt::Vertical headerData of QSqlQueryModel increasing numbers when doing pagination

Tags: c++, qt, header

im doing simple pagination with QSqlQueryModel select from limit query's
every thing is working fine . but. now i like to reflect the Vertical headerData of the QTableView .
im implementing the headerData , beacose it is const function i can't do any calculation inside it . so i have problem to calculate the right numbers in the Vertical headers. for example is im getting the rows from 20 to 30 .
i like the Vertical header show the numbers 20 to 30 . and so on ...
this is how i implement the headerData :

```
QVariant PlayListSqlModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const 
{

    if(orientation == Qt::Vertical && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        return section;
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
            switch (section)
            {
            case 0:
                return QString("name");
            case 1:
                return QString("From");
            case 2:
                return QString("Created Time");
            case 3:
                return QString("last name");
            case 4:

            }
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

UPDATE:
i even try to call const function that do the calculate , but still i have compilation error on the new const function :
 error C2166: l-value specifies const object

```
int PlayListSqlModel::calculateVerticalHeader()  const 
{
    int returnHeaderCount = m_iHeaderCount;
    m_iHeaderCount++;
    return returnHeaderCount;

}


QVariant PlayListSqlModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const 
{

    if(orientation == Qt::Vertical && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        return calculateVerticalHeader();
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
            switch (section)
            {
            case 0:
                return QString("Clip");
            case 1:
                return QString("From");
            case 2:
                return QString("Created Time");
            case 3:
                return QString("Rating");
            case 4:
                return QString("Feed");
            case 5:
                return QString("Double click to watch");
            }
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have an accessible member variable containing the current page you could simply multiply it with the number of rows per page + row.

```
  if(orientation == Qt::Vertical && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        return QString("%1").arg(m_currentPage*m_rowsPerPage+section);
    }
```

But as Alxx said, you thinking that you can't do any calculations is probably because you fail to call non const methods that return the variables i used in the example above, right?

**Update**
The reason you get **error C2166: l-value specifies const object** is because you try to increment the class variable: **m_iHeaderCount++** which is not allowed within a const declarated method. You may modify local variables within the headerData method but not class variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , what is the best way to make global variable that will hold the cound ? to make variable outside the scop of the class or to create dummy class that hold the counter value ?

Comment: How do you currently get the next X(page of) rows? By clicking some button or by scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

`>>`beacose it is const function i can't do any calculation inside it
You have odd understanding of `const` in C++. Const function cannot modify `this` object or call non-const functions, that's all. Your model knows current page and page size, isn't it? If so, it can calculate row numbers. If your utility functions like `currentPage()` and `rowCount()` (or whatever) are non-const, mark 'em so. It is good practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks! but why when i do :
if(orientation == Qt::Vertical && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
 {
  int returnHeaderCount = m_iHeaderCount;
  m_iHeaderCount++;
  return m_iHeaderCount;
 }
im getting :
error C2166: l-value specifies const object

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing exaclty what is needed. The `section` variable tells what row (in case the `orientarion` is `Qt::Vertical`) needs to be processed. And if you want to return just a number of the row you can just return `QVariant(QString::number(section))`

Comment: the problem is that the section is returning always from 0 ..to N
i need if i do pagination to get from 0-20 then 20 -40 and so on ..
for this i need to do calculation